# Form autocomplete fields populating incorrectly

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I've created a form for a site that I'm developing as follows:

```
<div class="container contacts__container--02">
    <? echo $this->Form->create('Email',array('class'=>'contact-form form','url'=>'/sendemail'));?>
    <form class="contact-form form contacts__form--02">
      <div class="contacts__form__inputs_box--02">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-2">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 contact_item">
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Your name"
              value=""
              name="data[Email][fullname]"
              class="input input--cloud-border input--white"
              minlength="3"
              required
            >
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 contact_item">
            <input
              type="text"
              required placeholder="Your business"
              value="" name="data[Email][business]"
              class="input input--cloud-border input--white"
            >
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-2">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 contact_item">
            <input
              type="email"
              required placeholder="Your email"
              value=""
              name="data[Email][email]"
              class="input input--cloud-border input--white"
              required
            >
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 contact_item">
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Your phone"
              value=""
              name="data[Email][phone]"
              class="input input--cloud-border input--white"
            >
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-2">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 contact_item">
            <input
              type="email"
              required placeholder="Your website"
              value="" name="data[Email][website]"
              class="input input--cloud-border input--white"
            >
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 contact_item">
            <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="How did you hear about us?"
            value="" name="data[Email][referer]"
            class="input input--cloud-border input--white"
          >
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-2">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-8 contact_item">
            <textarea
              required placeholder="Your message"
              value="" name="data[Email][message]"
              class="contacts__form_textarea--02 input input--cloud-border input--white"
            ></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row submit_row">
          <div class="col-md-2">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-8 submit_button">
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<?php echo $siteKey ?>"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row submit_row">
          <div class="col-md-2">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-8 contact_item">
            <a id="sendForm" class="contacts__form_button--02 button button--yellow button--small-radius">send</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-2">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-8 contact_item">
            <div id="response">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
      <? echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
    </div>
 </div>
```

But for some reason when I go to fill the form in all the fields, except for phone number are populated with my email address:

[image]

How can I set what autocomplete field should be used?

Comment: are you using chrome with it's saved values for your forms - it is sometimes rubbish at filling in fields - it depends what you call them as it looks for standard field names and as you seem to have `[email]` as all of your names, it will fill them in as email as it must do some sort of pattern match for email in the input name.  A question would be why have you called your array email, why not call it details or something more generic?

Comment: Do you want to disable Autocomplete?

Answer (score 0):

It was interpreting 'Email' as the field name rather than the form array. Changed to 'ContactForm' and it works fine now:

```
<? echo $this->Form->create('ContactForm',array('class'=>'contact-form form','url'=>'/sendemail'));?>
    <form class="contact-form form contacts__form--02">
      <div class="contacts__form__inputs_box--02">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-2">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 contact_item">
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Your name"
              value=""
              name="data[ContactForm][fullname]"
              class="input input--cloud-border input--white"
              minlength="3"
              required
            >
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 contact_item">
            <input type="text" required placeholder="Your business" value="" name="data[ContactForm][business]" class="input input--cloud-border input--white">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-2">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 contact_item">
            <input type="email" required placeholder="Your email" value="" name="data[ContactForm][email]" class="input input--cloud-border input--white">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 contact_item">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Your phone" value="" name="data[ContactForm][phone]" class="input input--cloud-border input--white">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-2">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-8 contact_item">
            <textarea required placeholder="Your message" value="" name="data[ContactForm][message]" class="contacts__form_textarea--02 input input--cloud-border input--white"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row submit_row">
          <div class="col-md-2">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-8 submit_button">
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<?php echo $siteKey ?>"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row submit_row">
          <div class="col-md-2">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-8 contact_item">
            <a id="sendForm" class="contacts__form_button--02 button button--yellow button--small-radius">send</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-2">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-8 contact_item">
            <div id="response">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
      <? echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```